# How to use podio-js in the browser (without Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sdk, podio

I'm sorry if this doesn't count as a "Programming Question" but I found it relevant since this will make me able to do programming in the Podio API.

My question/problem is that I can't figure out the correct way to set up the Podio JavaScript SDK/API scripts. I followed "http://podio.github.io/podio-js/" but it really only explains so much.. Mostly about Node and that I need to use Node for it, but isn't there another way like simple Ajax calls?

Reason being, I don't have the possibility of running a Node server in my server background, just to make API calls, it may be effective but it sounds kind of stupid when so many other API's out there doesn't require this.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> podio-js is a Podio JavaScript SDK for node and the browser.

... which means you don't necessary need Node.js. To use NPM module in the browser you'll need a bundler, like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io):

```
npm install podio-js --save
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

Then in your `app.js`:

```
var podio = require('podio-js');
// follow the tutorial
```

To bundle the app:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack app.js app.bundle.js
```

Then include the bundle in your HTML via script tag and voilà:

```
<script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: That makes alot more sense... I'll tested a few things and tried what you said ... works like a charm. Thanks!